# Load enviroment data in a project which has been added as dependency to another Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to add a project as a dependency to a Spring boot project.
I can't use a maven multimodule approach.

Now in this project I'm exposing a service that is sending queries to a Database. The Database connection data needs to be set from the main Project application.properties.

How can I access the data from the main project? Should I use Spring in the "dependency project" too?

Could you point me in the right direction ? Is this even possible?

Any help is greatly appriciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in a very very convinient way.

I developed my service with a spring boot application + spring-data. When I was done with this service (development testing etc.) I packaged it as a jar.

This jar included only the models, repositories and the services. All Spring configurations have been excluded.

I added this jar as a dependency to my other Spring boot project and changed my @EntityScan and @EnableJpaRepositories to include the packages from the dependency.

My annotations look like this now:

```
@....
@EntityScan("my.package.entities", "dependency.package.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories("my.package.repositories", "dependency.package.repositories")
@....
public class JpaConfiguration extends BaseJpaConfiguration
```

My dependency models and repositories used automatically the spring configuration from the parent project.

I don't know if this is the best way to go about this, I only have a little experience with spring.

If you have any advice to do this in a better way, please write it here.

Thanks for woatching.